# Error While publishing

Tags: umbraco

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$body$prop_bodytext="

Dit kontoudtog vi...").

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$body$prop_bodytext="

Dit kontoudtog vi...")

Anybody know what is this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the `requestValidation` setting in your web.config.

Set the the value of `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` in your web.config.

See [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297679/A-potentially-dangerous-Request-Form-value-was-det) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As the other question suggests, a quick fix is to change the validation mode, allowing any values to be submitted.

You should understand that this is likely because of the value being submitted by your controls. ASP.NET detects it as being a possible [script injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

This error is an exception that is generated to trap such attacks so disabling it might not be the best tactic. Instead, try and find out what the part of the submitted string value is that is causing the exception. This way you can trap it on form postback.

In the early days of ASP.NET, this kind of attack was left to the developer to trap. However, this led to undesirable security situations which undermined the reputation of ASP.NET.